# ¿Cómo cambiar el nombre a varias columnas de un sf?

Tags: r, rstudio, dataframe, names

He cargado un shapefile a Rstudio que luego he convertido a sf

```
#cargo directorio
setwd("C:/Users/XXX/XXX/XXX")
#le pido que me diga qué archivos .shp hay en la carpeta
ogrListLayers(".")
#le pido info sobre el shp que me interesa
ogrInfo(".","BDD_Covid19(05Agosto)")
#Ahora el archivo que me interesa se va a llamar "bdd_shp"
bdd_shp<-readOGR(".","BDD_Covid19(05Agosto)")
#Convierrto el archivo a sf, que es un formato más simple de shp con el que se trabaja en R.
bdd_sf <- st_as_sf(bdd_shp)
```

Pero al hacer esta conversión los nombres de las columnas han cambiado. Es decir, si antes existía una columna llamada "LN_TasaCasos_15Mar_29Mar" ahora, por defecto, ha sido cambiada por "Ln_TasaCasos1". Son más de 300 columnas en total, todas con problemas similares.

Lo que estoy buscando es que **todas** vuelvan a su nombre "original" ("LN_TasaCasos_15Mar_29Mar" en el ejemplo)

Como ya tenía los nombres "originales" en un archivo Excel, hice lo siguiente con la intención de cambiar los nombres a todas.

```
#cambio el nombre de las variables para que esté igual que en el excel
names(bdd_sf) <- c("ABSCodi_1","NOMABS","CODISS","NOMSS","CODIRS","NOMRS","CODIAGA","NOMAGA","ABSok","TasaCasos_15Mar_29Mar","LN_TasaCasos_15Mar_29Mar","TasaCasos_7DIASantes_15Mar_29Mar","Ln_TasaCasos_7DIASantes_15Mar_29Mar","TasaCasos_30Mar_13Abr","Ln_TasaCasos_30Mar_13Abr","TasaCasos_7DIASantes_30Mar_13Abr","Ln_TasaCasos_7DIASantes_30Mar_13Abr","TasaCasos_14Abr_25Abr","Ln_TasaCasos_14Abr_25Abr","TasaCasos_7DIASantes_14Abr_25Abr","Ln_TasaCasos_7DIASantes_14Abr_25Abr","TOTAL_14mar","TOTAL_Confin","TasaCasosTot","TasaCasosPCR4MAY","TasaCasosElisa4may","TasaCasosRapido4May","TasaCasosEpid4May","Ln_TasaCasosTot","Ln_TasaCasos14Mar","Ln_TasaCasosConfin","CasosTot4May","PCR4May","Elisa4May","Rapido4May","Epid4May","pr_direcivo","pr_tecnico_prof","pr_tecnico_apoyo","pr_empl_admin","pr_restaur_comerc",...,"Shape_Length","Shape_Area")
```

Llevo horas esperando a que el resultado esté listo pero pareciera que la función es demasiado pesada.

Hay alguna otra forma de cambiar los nombres de todas las columnas? Como mencioné, ya tengo el listado de los nombres "originales".

Comment: Cambiar los nombres de un `data.frame` es trivial para R, el cambio debiera ser inmediato, puedes probar con `colnames(df) <- tus_nombres` que es un poco más específico. De cualquier manera también es raro el cambio de nombres.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución sigue casi el mismo camino que el comentario hecho por Patricio Moracho, pero en vez de `colnames()`, usé solo `names ()` y la ubicación de las variables. En mi caso,
cambié desde la variable N° 10 hasta la N° 323.

```
    #Las funciones anteriores demoraban mucho, más rápido fue hacer esto con cada una de las variables
names(bdd_sf)[10]<-"TasaCasos_15Mar_29Mar"
.
.
.
names(bdd_sf)[323]<-"Shape_Area"
```